# using std::sort() on an array

Tags: arrays, file, sorting

I have a program which I have got to take numbers from a text file, add them to an array and write them to a file.
  I need to sort the numbers in the array using the std::sort() function call. My first attempt at it was this:

```
void ArrayIntStorage::sortStd()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++ i)
    {
        arrayStorage[i].sort();
    }
}
```

"n" is a constant for the size of the array. I know this is wrong but im not sure how to takle it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First read up the documentation of sort() [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/algorithm/sort)

Remove the loop and just try

```
std::sort(arrayStorage, arrayStorage + n);
```